# How to filter an XML field on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, cross-apply

I have a table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    XmlField xml NULL,
    /// Some other fields
)
```

The XML field contains an XML representation of a C# `Dictionary<int, string>`. E.g :

```
<dictionary>
    <item>
        <key><int>1</int></key>
        <value><string>Web</string></value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key><int>2</int></key>
        <value><string>Email</string></value>
    </item>
    // more item
</dictionary>
```

What I want to do is select all rows where XmlField contains (key = 1 with value = 'Web') and also contains (key = 2 with value = 'Email').

So far I have only managed to filter rows for 1 unique key/value match:

```
SELECT TableId, XmlField FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY XmlField.nodes('/dictionary/item') x(fields)
WHERE (x.fields.value('(key/int/text())[1]', 'int') = 1 
AND x.fields.value('(value/string/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') = 'Web')
```

If I add `AND (x.fields.value('(key/int/text())[1]', 'int') = 2 AND x.fields.value('(value/string/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') = 'Email')` then nothing is returned (quite logically).

I have also tried not to use `CROSS APPLY` and do a simple filter as such:

```
SELECT TableId, XmlField FROM MyTable
WHERE XmlField.exist('/dictionary/item/key/int[text() = 1]') = 1
AND XmlField.exist('/dictionary/item/value/string[text() = "Web"]') = 1
```

But then it acts like a `OR` and would return rows where the xml contains 2 key-value pairs such as (1, Email) and (2, Web)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```sql
select *
from MyTable as T
where T.XmlField.exist('/dictionary[item[key/int/text() = 1 and value/string/text() = "Web"] and   
                                    item[key/int/text() = 2 and value/string/text() = "Email"]]') = 1
```

Comment: Simply perfect. Looks like I need a crash course in XPath! Thanks a lot